# Rails: How to model following logic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, database-design

I have a model called Item, which belongs to Report.

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :report
end
```

For my Item, I want to have an attribute called item_category(besides other attributes).

```
t.string "item_category"
```

I will have some standard categories that will have a tax associated with them.

My question is:
Should I have another two models for Category and Tax, and load the available categories that will be created as options for my Item category attribute ? (or Tax should be an attribute for a Category model, or none of them)

After some time, another category can be added/removed, same for the Tax and I want this to be as modular as possible, not to make changes every time I want to remove/add category/tax.
How should I approach it?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how frequently categories will change. If tax + category pair is constant, then I would suggest adding that in code, as a constant (Hash, maybe, structured as { "category" : "tax" }). If taxes will change often, then it makes more sense of making another `Category` model and storing your tax + Category stuff there.

From your description it doesn't seem like you need a separate `Tax` model (I assume you will only have % amount there). This is based on an assumption that Category has only one tax.

That is all I can suggest with the information you have provided. But the most optimal methid laregly depends on more details description of your business logic

Comment: Taxes and categories are not supposed to changed frequently( if needed, once or twice in a 6 months timeline). Forgot to add - I want to add access to an admin (in admin rails ) to change them - maybe a separate Category model would suit this?

Comment: Yes, If you want someone else to be able to change them than a Category model is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the model

- Model: Categorytax

  - category:string
  - taxProcent: integer